# How to one hot encode numpy array of arrays using keras to_categorical?

Tags: numpy, keras

I have target data `y_tr` in shape `(92107, 49)` where each sample (row) is an array of length 49. I would like to loop over `y_tr` and one hot encode each array. I have been using keras `to_categorical` though I am facing an `Indexerror`.

Array in `y_tr`:

```
array([ 379,  379,  379,  252, 4166,  391,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0], dtype=int32)
```

The number of classes to encode each integer index = 10,000. (I do not wish to encode zero values):

```
onehots=[]
for seq in y_tr[:,1:]:
    try:
        onehots.append(to_categorical(seq - 1, num_classes=tar_vocab_size, dtype=np.int32))
    except IndexError as e:
        raise e

76   n = y.shape[0]
     77   categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes), dtype=dtype)
---> 78   categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
     79   output_shape = input_shape + (num_classes,)
     80   categorical = np.reshape(categorical, output_shape)

IndexError: index 28350 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10000
```

Comment: @Kaveh thanks for your response. The problem I am dealing with is text generation where at each timestep (49 timesteps) during inference, the model chooses from a probability distribution (size 10,000) to generate the next word in the sentence. Thus, there are 10000 classes. I was wondering if there is an efficient method to encode only the indices in the array corresponding to each unique word rather than assigning a 10,000 sized one hot vector for every single value. I am also finding trouble onehotencoding my numpy data with OneHotEncoder. Thanks for your help

Comment: Here is an example of generating Shakespeare words, take a look at this: https://github.com/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/1f240742b26dd336613ed69a6d44e1d6781a147c/TensorFlow%20In%20Practice/Course%203%20-%20NLP/NLP_Week4_Exercise_Shakespeare_Answer.ipynb

Comment: Hey I just took a look at the link you sent, thanks. I noticed in the cell before the sequential model build that the labels for training are one-hot encoded using keras' to_categorical. The number of classes are set to the size of the vocabulary similar to what i did. Could you please explain how creating embeddings are enough to train the model?

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I was at least a little bit wrong, so I deleted my comments. Actually you don't need to one_hot encode inputs, and embedding and tokenizing will handle the input features. But for labels, you need to.